# How to calculate sample size, power, and effect size?

Tags: sample-size, effect-size, statistical-power

We are trying to do a randomized controlled trial on patients. For a certain diseases patients, we want to know whether or not intervention improves their quality of life or not. We're dividing the patients into two groups: one receive the traditional method, other receives the intervention where their vitals and labs are checked with responses to some questionnaires about their quality of life is collected in 2 weeks, 4 weeks, 3 months, and 6 months. Whereas, for the traditional method, we're only going to follow up with patient in 1 month and 6 months. The lab and vitals for the traditional methods are only taken at 6 months.

For this, we'd like to know the power and sample size of the study. I would like to either know how to calculate it, or would like to know what I must know before I ask statistician's help. I read Cohen's article A Power Primer which help me make some sense, but I'm still somewhat confused about effect size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have the funds, I strongly suggest collecting pre-intervention data for the traditional method group. This will allow a stronger (more valid) study. Your current design suffers from a threat to ***ecological validity*** such that you lose ability to make causal claims. Also, again if you can afford it, add a control group.

In making the calculation you want, you need one of the numbers. Normally, you have a *minimum detectable effect size* that you set before hand, along with your acceptable $\alpha$ type-1 error rate and $1-\beta$ desired power. Having these values gives you the required $n$ sample size Such an analysis a *a priori*. On the other hand, if you have access to a restricted sample size $n$, acceptable $\alpha$ type-1 error rate, and $1-\beta$ desired power, you would learn your minimum detectable effect size, called *sensitivity analysis*.

I use `G*Power`, a free software, to do such calculations.

Comment: thank you. Effect size is what's causing me confusion. We don't have fund for the pre-intervention study, so was hoping to find any statistical method to find an estimate of the sample size. I'll download G*power

Comment: That was difficult for me, too. Think of it like a microscope. To see something smaller, you need stronger magnification. Likewise, to find a small effect size, you need either: a bigger sample, a bigger power, or a higher acceptable α.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating a bit on Jay's excellent answer and assuming that your experiment's outcome of interest is a proportion:

In order to determine a sample Size for a **2-Proportion** $Z\text{-test}$ , you need to specify:

1. the desired $α$ level

   - i.e., your willingness to commit a Type I error
2. the desired $β$ level

   - i.e., your willingness to commit a Type II error
   - (this equivalent to *desired power*)
3. a meaningful difference from the value of the parameter that is specified in the `Null`

   - i.e., you need to specify an "**Alternative**" *hypothesis value*

This is because rearranging the *2-Proportion* $Z\text{-test}$ [formula](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Agresti-Statistical-Methods-for-the-Social-Sciences-5th-Edition/PGM334444.html) (for equal Treatment and Control group sizes) gives us the minimum sample size needed  $\, \tilde{n}$:

$$\tilde{n} = (p_1(1-p_1)+p_2(1-p_2))\left(\dfrac{Z_{power}+Z_{1-\alpha}}{p_1-p_2}\right)^2$$

where

- $p_1$ is your current proportion that has a *high* "quality of life"
- $p_2$ is your current proportion that has a *high* "quality of life" +  `minimum` *effect size*

  - this is the *prespecified* minimum proportional that you choose to be able to detect
- $ \tilde{n}$ is the minimum  total sample size needed

  - i.e., it is the sum of *both* the Treatment and the Control groups

---

w.r.t. not doing this calculation manually, one superb open-source solution is to use **R**-language's [`pwr` library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/pwr.pdf).

The specific function in this case is the `pwr.2p.test`

- For any of `pwr`'s functions, you enter three of the four quantities (effect size, sample size, significance level, power) and the fourth is calculated.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. This is very helpful.